# How to remove unwanted ";" before explode php

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to explode the txt file in one array per line. The file was give through a URL on this format:

```
Ville:Montr&#233;al; Fichier:montreal.txt
Ville:Qu&#233;bec; Fichier:quebec.txt
```

The problem it that the separator variable ";" is the same found in some other parts of the string.

The wanted result is:

```
[0] => Ville:Québec [1] => Fichier:quebec.txt
[0] => Ville:Montréal [1] => Fichier:montreal.txt
```

I am using this code:

```
<?php $tabCities = file ('redacted'); ?>

<?php //$oneLine = utf8_decode ($tabCities[0]); ?>
<?php $oneLine = $tabCities[0]; ?>

<?php $arrayLine = explode(";", $oneLine); ?>

<?php print_r ($oneLine); ?>
<?php print_r ($arrayLine); ?>
```

It outputs

```
Ville:Montréal; Fichier:montreal.txt Array ( [0] => Ville:Montré [1] => al [2] => Fichier:montreal.txt )
```

`utf8_decode` does not help. Is there any other function or strategy I can try?

Comment: These are called "HTML entities" and you need to [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

It will convert the html entity (`&#233;`) into a unicode character to `é`